# ASP.NET - Working with Oracle 9i Database / Database Stored Procedures

Tags: asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle9i

.
Hi,

We are building an ASP.NET application with C#.net language and Oracle 9i database.  Here we installed Oracle 9i client software on our PCs.

We never worked on Oracle 9i database.  It’s the first time.

We are planning to build stored procedures in Oracle database and call them from our ASP.NET application.  Does working with Oracle stored procedures and ASP.NET is similar to that of working with MS SQL Server stored procedures and ASP.NET?

Would you please also suggest if there any good reference tutorials / web references for this topic (Working with ASP.NET and Oracle 9i database stored procedures) so that we can study, understand and apply the concepts in our application.

Many Thanks,
Regards,
Arti. 
.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) since Microsoft decided not to develop Oracle drivers any more (see article [Oracle and ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7.aspx) ).

On home page for [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) you will find links to number of tutorials and technical articles on accessing Oracle with ADO.NET.